# How to declare a variable inside a IQueryable.Select Method?

Tags: linq, linq-to-entities

My problem is that in this line  Remaining =Amount-Cost, 
Is there a way to declare a variable within the Select that I can the reuse within the linq select? I don't want to call _myContext.BudgetDocItems.Where(z => z.SL.TLRef == x.SL.TLRef).Select(y => y.Amount).Sum() twice.

```
var test = myContext.BudgetDocItems.Select(x => new BudgetDocItem1
    {
        Amount = myContext.BudgetDocItems.Where(z => z.SL.TLRef == x.SL.TLRef).Select(y => y.Amount).Sum(),
        Cost = myContext.AccDocItemViews.Where(z => z.SLRef == x.SLRef).Select(y => y.Debit).Sum(),
        Remaining =Amount-Cost    }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 3):

First select the values, then use them:

```
var test = myContext.BudgetDocItems

.Select(x => new
    {
        Amount = myContext.BudgetDocItems.Where(z => z.SL.TLRef == x.SL.TLRef).Sum(y => y.Amount),
        Cost = myContext.AccDocItemViews.Where(z => z.SLRef == x.SLRef).Sum(y => y.Debit)
    })

.Select(x => new BudgetDocItem1
    {
        Amount = x.Amount,
        Cost = x.Cost,
        Remaining = x.Amount - x.Cost
    })
.ToList();
```